# What’s the simplest known Italian vegetable stock recipe?

Tags: soup, italian-cuisine

There may be many recipes for vegetable stock in Italian cuisine, but which is the simplest requiring the fewest ingredients?

Answer (score 2):

It’s not about ‘fewest ingredients’.  It’s about simplicity of preparation and reducing food waste:

1. Go through your fridge and collect up any sad looking vegetables or vegetables
2. Clean them (cut out any bad sections, wash off any soil, etc)
3. Throw them into a pot and cover with water
4. Simmer

Some people also collect up a ‘scrap bag’ in their freezer with stems from herbs, rinds from cheese (unwaxed), bones, etc.

Italians are going to have Mediterranean vegetables and herbs for the most part, so it’s going to come out ‘Italian’.  The only thing that you need to avoid from Italian cooking is citrus — the rinds will make it horribly bitter.

Comment: Thanks. How long could such a stock stay good in the fridge?

Comment: @PeterElbert : It depends on how well sanitized everything is when you put it up, and how quickly you cool it down.  If you're not experienced with these sorts of thing, you should try to use it within 2-3 days.